# Programmatic Download on Synapse by Python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, azure-synapse

I'm trying run a code on Colab, but I've run into some issues while downloading data from Synapse.

Here is the download link for the data
https://www.synapse.org/#!Synapse:syn3193805/files/

Upon entering the website, clicking on the download option at the upper right corner reveals a programmatic option. I chose to download using Python.

You will then get a block of code as follows.

```
import synapseclient
import synapseutils

syn = synapseclient.Synapse() 
syn.login('synapse_username','password')
files = synapseutils.syncFromSynapse(syn, ' syn3193805 ')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWRQL.png)

However, I encountered recurring error message when running the code".

```
WARNING:synapseclient_default:
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ifcollision=overwrite.localis being IGNORED because the download destination is synapse's cache. Instead, the behavior is "overwrite.local". 
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

At first, I noticed that there were unnecessary spaces on both sides of the file ID. I removed them, but I still encountered the same error."

-Before-

```
files = synapseutils.syncFromSynapse(syn, ' syn3193805 ')
```

-After-

```
files = synapseutils.syncFromSynapse(syn, 'syn3193805')
```

I also thought that this message may not affect the program's operation, so I waited for a long time. However, it remained stuck and continued to spin.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAmv5.png)

Has anyone ever encountered a similar issue before? How can it be resolved? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved the problem myself.
Just need to specify the download path for the data.

```
import synapseclient
import synapseutils

syn = synapseclient.Synapse()
syn.login('synapse_username','password')

destination_folder = "C:\\Users\\XXX\\Desktop\\Project"
files = synapseutils.syncFromSynapse(syn, 'syn3193805', path=destination_folder)
```